# Simple loop for Android

Tags: android, loops, textview, imageview

I think this is a simple and easy question and I'd like to help. I have a for loop that just add text. My question is, Could add **TextView + ImageView per line**?

```
ImageView img  = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.pasar);
TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtrecorrido21);

tv.setText("");

for (int x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
     tv.append("Text1");
     tv.append("Text2");
}
```

Regards!

Comment: what are you really want to do?

Comment: @HamidShatu I would like a text and a picture, then another text and image ... and so ...

Comment: do you want to create listview item?

Comment: @HamidShatu No, my intention is not to use listview. Previously used listview and I did not like the result in a custom dialog

Comment: where you want add these view, post that code, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LinearLayout: (and assuming dialog is your inflated layout)

```
    int N = 10; //NumberOfTextandImages    
    LinearLayout L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            View dialog= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog1,null,false);
            ImageView img  = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.pasar);
            TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtrecorrido21);
            for (int x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
               tv.append("Text1");
               tv.append("Text2");
            }
            L1.addView(dialog);
        }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! But The method AddView (View) in the ViewGroup type is not applicable for the arguments (Dialog).I create the dialog with : final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

Comment: You can't add dialogs to views like this! why does it need to be a dialog? just inflate another layout with one image and one textview.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that you want *"a text and a picture, then another text and imgae ... and so ..."*. In that case, a **List View** is the recommended control of choice.

- [List View | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Basically, you would

- create a *template* (layout resource file) for your list items, which would contain a TextView and an ImageView,
- create an *Adapter* in code and fill it with the data you want to show. In your case, a simple [**ArrayAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout (xml) with a LinearLayout that holds an ImageView and a TextView, then inflate this layout in the for loop, set the according image and text and add the layout wherever you want...

If you always have the same number of image/text - elements as it seems since your for loop only runs twice, you should simply add those two "rows" in your layout file...